# ご無沙汰いたしました — OK for electronic communications?

Tags: politeness, set-phrases, greetings

In a recent [comment exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38494/what-does-jus-folks-is-jus-dumb-mean/38496#38496) on ELU.SE, a Japanese man (my senior in years, and a "guest" in the forum whose questions I had answered regularly for some time, but not much lately as I have been scaling back my participation there), said in his comment to my response:

> お久しぶりです。

I felt obliged to respond in kind with

> ご無沙汰いたしました。

and that is how I replied. But it just felt a little strange in a comment-chain discussion. What do you think? Might こちらこそ or something else have been better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to the post's title, I think, yes, it's OK for electronic communications.  But `ご無沙汰しています` (it's usually 〜ています or 〜ております) sounds weird for such a casual acquaintance (if he's even that much to you).  I think it's reserved for very close and/or very important relationships (extended family members, past teachers/professors/senpai, old friends, etc.).  For just an acquaintance, I'd probably just respond with an equal `久しぶりですね`.

I'm not sure of `こちらこそ` in this situation.  It sounds fine to *me*, but I'll let someone else more knowledgeable comment on that.

---

**EDIT**: I did find some examples where it was ご無沙汰**しました／いたしました** and had the same meaning.  Guess I learned something.